# SSL cert error when connecting to Adafruit IO

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, iot, adafruit

It seems that the Adafruit-io library is not working with newest version of Python (3.9.1).  Connecting to the Adafruit IO server gives an SSL cert error.

When I was running Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8, this code worked fine.

```
import sys
import time
from Adafruit_IO import MQTTClient      # pip install adafruit-io

ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = 'MY_ADAFRUIT_KEY'
ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = 'MY_ADAFRUIT_NAME'
IO_FEED = 'MY_FEED'

def connected(client):
    print ('Connected to Adafruit IO! Listening for feed changes...')
    client.subscribe(IO_FEED)

def disconnected(client):
    print ('Disconnect from Adafruit IO!')
    sys.exit(1)

def message(client, feed_id, payload):
    # feed_id or {0} represents the name of the feed in the message to the Adafruit IO service.
    # Payload or {1} represents the value being sent.
    print ('Feed {0} recieved new vaule: {1}'.format(feed_id, payload))

    if '{1}'.format(feed_id, payload) == "ON":
        print("ON Worked ")
    if '{1}'.format(feed_id, payload) == "OFF":
        print("OFF worked ")

client = MQTTClient(ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)

client.on_connect    = connected
client.on_disconnect = disconnected
client.on_message    = message
client.loop_background()
client.connect()

while True:
    # publish data to the feed here
    time.sleep(10)
```

I've upgraded to Python 3.9.1, and I get the following connection error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryan/Code/gdgIOT/subscribe.py", line 33, in <module>
    client.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Adafruit_IO/mqtt_client.py", line 150, in connect
    self._client.connect(self._service_host, port=self._service_port,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 941, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1104, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: no, i'm not behind a firewall

Comment: Note: I've found that it works fine in Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8, but it errors in 3.9